# Change DataGrid cell color based on value condition if its 0 then it should display gray else Yellow using MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

## I am trying to apply the cell background color after binding a table to the grid using MVVM WPF design, i need the output in the below format as attached.

[image]

I tried to apply background color for each cell before binding it to the grid view

Below is my DataGrid Code

```cs
                     CollectionViewSource collectionView = new CollectionViewSource();
                     collectionView.Source = dtStatus;
                     DataTable newDt = SetBackgroundColor(dtStatus);
                     WorkFlowGridCollectionView = newDt;
```

## I tried Method to set the YourBackgroundColorProperty :

```
    private void SetBackgroundColor(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTable ddtt = new DataTable();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
            for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                string cell = row[j].ToString();
                int cellValue = Convert.ToInt32(cell);

                // Assuming you have some condition to check for background color change
                if (cellValue > 0)
                {
                    YourBackgroundColorProperty = Brushes.Yellow.ToString(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    YourBackgroundColorProperty = Brushes.Gray.ToString(); /
                }                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a binding for the background to the value of the field (property of the row context element) in the style or cell template and set your custom converter for this binding.

Comment: <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding YourBackgroundColorProperty,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>

Comment: I have already added the dataCell tag and added like this in the view <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00FF00"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>-->
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>

Answer (score 0):

Add a `DataTrigger` to each `CellStyle` of each column that sets the `Background` to `Gray` if the corresponding column (named "YourColumn" in the example below) in the current row of the `DataTable` is 0:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00FF00"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourColumn}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```